# Entity Framework and pre-existing models mapping

Tags: entity-framework, model

I already have a project with all of my models in it.

I want to use EF 6 to call stored procs.

And when the data is passed to and from the stored proc, I want EF to handle the object model mapping

Is that possible?

I am using MVC.net and c#

Thanks!

Comment: You can use your model class as Poco class and create a datacontext class to hold all the mappings. Also you can call stored procedure using entity framework.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely possible with EF6! [See this tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/async-and-stored-procedures-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application) (scroll past the bit on async) for a quick and easy way to map your entities to CRUD based stored procs.

Comment: I see a very good example in the link you posted for how to use stored procedures.  

The second part of my question is still a little fuzzy = How can I use my existing Models instead of the Entities in the example?

Thanks!

Comment: I think Bappi Datta had it correct: You have to declare some DbSet properties within your DbContext class e.g. 

public class MyContext : DbContext 
{ 
    public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; } 
    public DbSet<Posts> Posts { get; set; } 
}